# why still getting inconsistent result when already use np.random.seed() and tf.random.set_seed()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, random-seed

I try to do NN classification using keras. I already use np.random.seed() and tf.random.set_seed() to get constant result everytime rerun it. I use random seed in my syntax around 1 month ago and at first it was work, but lately I rerun my code and getting difference result again. The syntax that I use is like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(0)
tf.random.set_seed(0)

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(100, input_dim= Train_X2_Tfidf.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
model1.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = Adam (learning_rate=0.01)
model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model1.summary()

es = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",mode='min',patience=10)
history1 = model1.fit(Train_X2_Tfidf, Train_Y2, epochs=200, verbose=1,
                    validation_split=0.2, batch_size=32, 
                    callbacks =[es])
```

And the result I get is:

```
Epoch 1/200
75/75 [==============================] - 3s 16ms/step - loss: 0.4355 - accuracy: 0.7976 - val_loss: 0.3175 - val_accuracy: 0.8620
```

The next run I get this result:

```
Epoch 1/200
75/75 [==============================] - 1s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4341 - accuracy: 0.7925 - val_loss: 0.3169 - val_accuracy: 0.8653
```

How to get same result for every rerun? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import os

def reset_seeds():
   os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = "123"
   np.random.seed(123) 
   random.seed(123)
   tf.random.set_seed(123)

reset_seeds()
```